# Android card game Random()

Tags: java, android, random, playing-cards

I am making a card game in java/android.  The idea is simple, a random card gets picked and shown and the player has to select if the next card is going to be higher or lower.  My question is how can I make it so that once a card is selected it cant be used anymore?

My plan was to create an array 0-51; then do a switch and case for all the possibilities.

Comment: You don't want a switch... you need to remove elements when they're selected. Shuffle a collection then pop from the top!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work. Think of your array like a stack of cards and shuffle it. Then just go through the array, starting at 0, to pick cards off the top.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Shuffle.html

If you want to be super cool, use a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) as the container for your cards, since that is most similar to how a real deck of cards operates.